# can't creating plist file in document folder

Tags: iphone

I have write code like this in `Viewdidload` method. But it don't create file `.plist`.

I don't know  whether code is wi8 or wrong. And where i have to write?

```
NSError *error;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory =  [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //2
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"data1.plist"]; //3
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

if ( ![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path] ) {
    NSString *pathToSettingsInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
    pathForResource:@"data1" ofType:@"plist"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just created a path to it, you should try loading it into a NSDictionary.

```
NSDictionary* mydictionary = [ NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: pathToSettingsInBundle];
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your if block add a second line

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:pathToSettingsInBundle toPath:path error:&error];
```

Comment: i get an error -[NSFileManager copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:]: source path like this if i add this line.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

plistpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Product.plist"]];
```

And then

```
[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; 

[Whatever [Array or Dictionary] you want to Write in Plist]
```

If it is still not creating the plist then check whether your array or dictionary must be empty.