# Unable to write to a plist file iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I read a lot of questions on stackoverflow regarding this and I have ensured, to copy my plist file from the bundle to the documents directory on first run. But, now when I try to write to this plist file, it doesn't write successfully.

```
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inAppList.plist"];
[infoDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"someKey"];
didWrite = [infoDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

didWrite comes out to be a 'NO'.

I am sure about the plist file being copied in the documents directory because I can see that in the organizer and my devices tab. Also I am able to read the file from the document directory successfully.

Might just be a very little mistake, but really can't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Are you sure your dictionary contains PLIST objects only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As similar as your code, the code maybe like below:

```
// get plist file path
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"inAppList.plist"];

// set '1' forKey "somebody"
NSArray *objectArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1],nil];
NSArray *keyArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"someKey",nil];
NSDictionary *infodict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objectArray forKeys:keyArray];

// write dictionary to file
BOOL didWrite = [infodict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 

plistpath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Product.plist"]];
```

And then

```
[array writeToFile:path atomically:YES]; 

[Whatever [Array or Dictionary] you want to Write in Plist]
```

If it is still not creating the plist then check whether your array or dictionary must be empty.

And one more thing: Be sure that you are not Inserting null value in plist. if you trying do it....then also it not be able to create plist.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community. If you're doing this then it usually means the questions are duplicates so flag them as such instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11273284/419

Comment: okkk.......Thanks for the info. i don't know about this. from now on wards i will take care about this.